GFCI at beginning of circuit wont reset
The GFCI in my garage is at the beginning of the circuit and won't reset. It has been working since we bought the home 4 years ago.
I replaced the GFCI exactly as the original. Still wouldn't reset, no breaker trips and it is getting power in. It is listed on the panel as being for garage outlets however my outside outlets won't work either.
I had power washed the outside of the house and thought water may have gotten into one of the outlets. Two outside outlets were very crust and rusted, I replaced both of those. Don't know how to check which outlet may be the issue as the GFCI wont reset so no power is going through the circuit.
Everything has been unplugged from the circuit.
Am I missing something here or is it time for me to call an electrician?

A typical GFCI/receptacle has "line" and "load" connections. The "load" connections are often taped over initially (Harper calls this the "for wizards only" tape).
When you install or replace a GFCI/receptacle or GFCI/deadfront (sometimes used as a switch, nothing plugged in directly), you need to start with "line" first. Connect the GFCI/receptacle to "line", turn on the breaker, reset if needed (some GFCI/receptacles may need an initial reset) and see if it works properly (able to power a plugged in device, TEST turns it off, RESET turns it back on).
If "line" by itself works then turn off the breaker again and connect the downstream receptacle wiring to the "load" connections, turn on the breaker and see if it works. If it doesn't work with "load" connected then the problem is in the wires, junction boxes or receptacles that are connected to "load". Which then means some methodical trouble-shooting to determine exactly where the problem is - e.g., a bad receptacle, connections still wet or possibly something else.

Thank you! Discovered it is the load side that is tripping it so I will run through the connections and receptacles again to see what I find. Much appreciated!!

@EricinGeorgia, the courteous action would be to accept the most helpful and correct answer. Take the tour https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour for more info.

@JimmyFix-it thank you for that, I upvoted but didn't accept, now done!
